# How can I create a column in my dataframe that maps to a list in R?

Tags: r, dictionary, dplyr

I have some license data and am trying to create a column in my dataframe that tells me whether the license listed is acceptable based on the program someone is enrolled in.

In order to do this, I created a list since some of the licenses are acceptable for more than one program. Ideally, what I was thinking was that I could then somehow use this list as a reference to see whether the program was listed under the license name. I also tried case_when, but kept getting errors. I also would prefer having a list that I can use as a kind of map because the license names will likely change from year to year.

**Sample code**

Below is an excerpt of my dataframe:

```r
df1 <- data.frame(Program = c("Elementary Education", "Elementary Education", "Secondary Math", "Secondary Math", "Secondary ELA", "Secondary ELA"), Licensure = c("Content Area - Elementary Education (Grades 1-6)", "Content Area - Secondary Math (Grades 7-12)", "Content Area - Secondary Math (Grades 7-12)", "Mathematics (Grades 7-12) 1706", "Content Area - Secondary ELA (Grades 7-12)", "Content Area - Early Childhood (preK-Grade 3)"))
```

Here is the list I created that includes all of the licenses with the acceptable programs underneath each:

```r
license_index <- list(
  "Content Area - Early Childhood (preK-Grade 3)" = "Elementary Education",
  "Content Area - Elementary Education (Grades 1-6)" = "Elementary Education",
  "Content Area - Middle Grades ELA (Grades 4-9)" = c("Elementary Education", "Secondary ELA"),
  "Content Area - Middle Grades Math (Grades 4-9)" = c("Elementary Education", "Secondary Math"),
  "Content Area - Middle School Mathematics (Grades 4-8)" = "Elementary Education",
  "Content Area - Secondary ELA (Grades 7-12)" = "Secondary ELA",
  "Content Area - Secondary Math (Grades 7-12)" = "Secondary Math",
  "Content Area - Secondary English (Grades 7-12)" = "Secondary ELA",
  "English Language Arts and Reading (Grades 4-8) 864" = "Elementary Education",
  "Core Subjects (Grades EC-6) 1770" = "Elementary Education",
  "English Language Arts and Reading (Grades 7-12) 1709" = "Secondary ELA",
  "Mathematics (Grades 4-8) 866" = "Elementary Education",
  "Mathematics (Grades 7-12) 1706" = "Secondary Math"
)
```

What I ideally would like as a final column would be whether the license and program are a match or not:

```r
ideal.df <- data.frame(Program = c("Elementary Education", "Elementary Education", "Secondary Math", "Secondary Math", "Secondary ELA", "Secondary ELA"), Licensure = c("Content Area - Elementary Education (Grades 1-6)", "Content Area - Secondary Math (Grades 7-12)", "Content Area - Secondary Math (Grades 7-12)", "Mathematics (Grades 7-12) 1706", "Content Area - Secondary ELA (Grades 7-12)", "Content Area - Early Childhood (preK-Grade 3)"), match = c("Match", "No", "Match", "Match", "Match", "No"))
```

I am thinking I need the mutate function and maybe using the purrr map function, but I am not super familiar with tidyverse and would really appreciate help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way with `tidyverse`, where we convert the named `list` to a two column data.frame with `enframe`, `right_join` with original dataset and create the `match` by comparing the column 'match' with 'Program'

```
library(tidyverse)
enframe(license_index, name = "Licensure", value = "match") %>%
    unnest %>% 
    right_join(df1) %>% 
    mutate(match = match == Program) %>%
    select(names(df1), everything())
# A tibble: 6 x 3
#  Program              Licensure                                        match
#  <fct>                <chr>                                            <lgl>
#1 Elementary Education Content Area - Elementary Education (Grades 1-6) TRUE 
#2 Elementary Education Content Area - Secondary Math (Grades 7-12)      FALSE
#3 Secondary Math       Content Area - Secondary Math (Grades 7-12)      TRUE 
#4 Secondary Math       Mathematics (Grades 7-12) 1706                   TRUE 
#5 Secondary ELA        Content Area - Secondary ELA (Grades 7-12)       TRUE 
#6 Secondary ELA        Content Area - Early Childhood (preK-Grade 3)    FALSE
```

---

Or we can make use of  [rap](https://github.com/romainfrancois/rap) package which can be helpful for this scenario

```
library(rap)
df1 %>% 
   rap(match = ~ license_index[[as.character(Licensure)]] == Program) %>%
   unnest
#              Program                                        Licensure match
#1 Elementary Education Content Area - Elementary Education (Grades 1-6)  TRUE
#2 Elementary Education      Content Area - Secondary Math (Grades 7-12) FALSE
#3       Secondary Math      Content Area - Secondary Math (Grades 7-12)  TRUE
#4       Secondary Math                   Mathematics (Grades 7-12) 1706  TRUE
#5        Secondary ELA       Content Area - Secondary ELA (Grades 7-12)  TRUE
#6        Secondary ELA    Content Area - Early Childhood (preK-Grade 3) FALSE
```

Comment: Both of these options worked nicely. Why do you need to unnest the data for this query?

Comment: @K.C.  If you check the `str` of the output before the `unnest`, the `match` is a `list column with one element each.  By unnesting, I am flattening it to a vector column

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
x<-stack(license_index)
x$values[match(df1$Licensure,x$ind)]==df1$Program
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

You can map the `TRUE` and `FALSE` values of the above with `Match` and `No` if needed.

Comment: This works well - thank you. To better understand this function, is the stack function turning the list into a dataframe?

Comment: Yep, indeed. `stack` repeats the name of the list for each element of it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really help you with tidyverse, but this base-R solution should work:

```
df1$match <-sapply(1:nrow(df1), function(i){
  ifelse(license_index[[which(names(license_index) == df1$Licensure[i])]] == df1$Program[i],'Match','No')})
```

Comment: That's helpful, thank you! I was thinking sapply might work, but wasn't sure just how, so I am appreciative of having it written out here.